# How do I take width and height of a custom pop-up window from the user?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a webpage where I take the input for width and height parameters from the user in an HTML file. Using JavaScript, I'm supposed to use the input provided by the user to open a pop-up window of custom size. Here's the code I've written but it doesn't work.

**HTML**:

```
<h4>5. Open pop-up window of custom size</h4>
Height: <input type="number" id="pHeight">
Width: <input type="number" id="pWidth">
<button onclick="customPopup()">Open custom pop-up</button>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
// 5. Open pop-window of custom size
function customPopup() {
  var h = document.getElementByID("pHeight").value;
  var w = document.getElementByID("pWidth").value;
  window.open ("http://google.com", "popup-custom", "status=1, scrollbars=1, width=w, height=h");
}
```

Comment: Is this useful to you. https://jsfiddle.net/g1bg5rty/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your selector is wrong.Its `document.getElementById` not `document.getElementByID` and also you need to pass `value of w and h` not `w and h as string`.try the below code:

```
<h4>5. Open pop-up window of custom size</h4>
    Height: <input type="number" id="pHeight">
    Width: <input type="number" id="pWidth">
    <button onclick="customPopup()">Open custom pop-up</button>
<script>
function customPopup() {

var h = document.getElementById("pHeight").value;
var w = document.getElementById("pWidth").value;

window.open ("http://google.com", "popup-custom", "status=1, scrollbars=1, width="+w+", height="+h);

}

</script>
```